# How to recover RStudio session after crash?

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

I would like to know how to restore my previous RStudio session after RStudio and the R session crashed.

Background:
I find that my R session crashes very often, at random times for random reasons. I am fine with that I guess.
Most of the time RStudio restarts the R session and I can continue.
But sometimes it just freezes at which time I noticed power cycling the entire machine allows RStudio to recover and even reload my old session.

Stupid me, I don't think power cycling is a good idea so I manually killed the R session, but then RStudio responded but was not really working so I restarted it and it came back with an empty work-space.

I have been backing up with Session->Save Workspace As, but it seems to do nothing as recovering leaves me with the blank empty environment.

I am looking to restore the RStudio display, including the command history , which for a novice like me is precious, and my list of open scripts, some of which were unsaved at the time of the crash.

I am assuming since RStudio can recover itself, there is a file somewhere I can use to recover it.

And if there is no way to recover, how can I completely save my workspace so this cannot happen again?

Also, is there a proper way to recover from an RStudio freeze without a hard reset?

Comment: Session / Load Workspace, if you know where you saved it. You can save and load the History pane directly too, if you like. Really, you should keep all your valuable code in R source files, though.

Comment: Load Workspace does not load anything but the same empty workspace I have now. It seems my saving has been useless. I also know about saving the history separately. But stopped a while ago assumption the worskpace had it covered.  Where does RStuio store the files it uses for recovery in a crash? Thanks.

Comment: This question really probably belongs [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts).

Comment: Thanks, You are right. I will ask it there as well. However I usually find better answers here.

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while since I asked this question. I was never able to fully recover, but I switched to Rprojects which is the recommended way to use Rstudio.

Rprojects are stored in a folder and they remember all files and data from that project in that folder.

This did not help me with my initial problem, but projects prevent it from happening again. The hard part is moving a work-space to a project if it was not in a project to start.

Comment: It would be better to add this an an update to the question as it does not answer the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the first step of this article helped me entirely.
https://datacornering.com/how-to-restore-closed-unsaved-script-in-rstudio/

Basically, if on windows, go to C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\RStudio\sources\s-xx and find a file with "-contents" at the end. This is your unsaved file.

Comment: Useless answer.