# Can I restore unsaved RMD file?

Tags: r

I used Rstudio and IOS systems.

I moved my RMD file from the desktop to a folder to prepare for submission without saving it before changing the places of RMD, which means it wasn’t the last version. I used R for most of my data cleaning process and indeed spent a lot of time on it. Is there any specific way to restore it?

Thanks very much for any potential help.

I tried restart the R. Check the recent files but nothing found

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70596929/6574038

Comment: This is for the window right?